# I want to extract the data given from a specific txt file and save it in excel or any spreadsheet app

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I have written a small script to get data from a website and store it in a txt file so that I can then extract specific data and then store it in an excel sheet. Until now I have been only able to write a few lines of code in python. I am just a beginner.

```
#Importing modules
import requests

import json

#Program start here
######################

#loading required info for post request
pload = {'iec':'0200006797','name':'GLOBA'}
# Sending request to web
r = requests.post('http://dgft.delhi.nic.in:8100/dgft/IecPrint',data = pload)




#opening file for saving the extacted data
f = open("data.txt", "w+")
f.write(r.text)

#Opening file for reading and further manipulations
f=open("data.txt","r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    contents = f.read()
```

---

So I basically want to extract data from this. I only want to extract the name and phone number of the first director, the name and phone number of the second director, and the name and phone number of the third director. The data is in HTML form. Also, the below HTML is not complete. There is more than one table so I just want to extract the data from the first table which says "Directors". Thanks.

```html
</TABLE> 
<BR> 
<BR> 
<B>Directors:</B> 
<BR> 
<TABLE BORDER=1>
<TR><TD VALIGN= TOP ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=50>1.</TD><TD VALIGN= TOP ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=100>SANJAY CHAKRABORTY                                <BR>LATE PRASAD KUMAR CHAKRABORTY                     <BR>19 K K MUKHERJEE SARANI,SERAMPORE  <BR>                                   <BR>HOOGHLY,WEST BENGAL                <BR>PIN-712204<BR>Phone/Email:919339624590                       </TD></TR>

<TR><TD VALIGN= TOP ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=50>2.</TD><TD VALIGN= TOP ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=100>SANJAY DHANUKA                                    <BR>BASUDEO DHANUKA                                   <BR>BA -206,SECTOR-1,SALT LAKE,PS-BIDH <BR>ANNAGAR                            <BR>KOLKATA,WEST BENGAL                <BR>PIN-700064<BR>Phone/Email:9674448777                         </TD></TR>

<TR><TD VALIGN= TOP ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=50>3.</TD><TD VALIGN= TOP ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=100>ISHITA NANDI                                      <BR>INDRANIL BURMAN ROY                               <BR>112, DR B C ROY SARANI,NEW BARRACK <BR>PORE                               <BR>KOLKATA,WEST BENGAL                <BR>PIN-700131<BR>Phone/Email:9804561441                         </TD></TR>


</TABLE>
```

Comment: Look into `BeautifulSoup`, `xml` and/or `xpath` queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example using lxml and xpath. This will export the data to csv file.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv    

    #loading required info for post request
pload = {'iec':'0200006797','name':'GLOBA'}
# Sending request to web
r = requests.post('http://dgft.delhi.nic.in:8100/dgft/IecPrint',data = pload)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

csvFile = open('directors.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
writer.writerow(('name', 'phonenumber'))

#find name and phone and create a list

contacts =[]

items = tree.xpath("//table/tbody/tr")

for item in items:
    names = item.xpath("//td[2]/text()[1]")
    phones = item.xpath("//td[2]/text()[7]")
    for name,phone in names,phones:
             contacts.append(name,phone)

#opening file for saving the extacted data
for contact in contacts:
    writer.writerow(contact)

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. The code was not completely working but with few modification I got it to work but the data that it puts in csv is not properly formatted I mean it puts all 3 directors name in one row and all the phone numbers in another and it repeats it 3 time. Also I am sharing the data that it produces. The below is what it produces : name phonenumber and than puts all the name in just one row and repeats it 3 times please help thank you!

Comment: So there is another table after this and it is giving data from that as well. And the other problems is that it is giving the name of all 3 directors in one cell only and phone number off all 3 in other I want all 3 directors name to be in different cell. And also it is producing some weird result. The code that you provide I made some specific changes like: 'items = tree.xpath("//table[2]/tr")' I changed table to 2 because I want from second table and than 'contacts.append((name,phone))' this line was throwing error so i put them in a brackets and than it is throwing error please run thanks

Comment: also if you can provide you email id than it would be great if not than also fine

Comment: also a last request. I want the data to be stored horizontally like The first row should include Direct 1   Phone Number   Director 2  Phone number  Director 3  Phone number and the rest name of the first diector comes under director 1 and his phone number goes in next to it and so on

Comment: i dont have access to your site. so i will not be of much help here. I have updated the result with some changes - for loops. it should print correct name and phone as a row item. If you need the data stored horizaontally, first have the headers defined correctly.then update the for loop to fetch what you need. The xpath are not too difficult and there are plenty of example in google.